# Differences between MongoDB's Map Reduce OutputType

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce, output

I want to use MongoDB's MapReduce functionality and access a large set of data. I'm using the

```
INLINE OutputType
    MapReduceCommand cmd = new MapReduceCommand(dbCollection, 
                MapReduceTest.map, 
                MapReduceTest.reduce, 
                null, 
                MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, 
                query);
```

This works fine, when dealing with small sets of data, however it can be used for manipulating data up to 16MB, which is a problem for me.
I want to access a really large set of data, but I haven't found any good documentation about the other options `MERGE, REDUCE, REPLACE`.
Does anyone knows the differences?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the text from the official docs:

> replace - Replace the contents of the  if the collection with the collectionName exists.
>
> merge - Merge the new result with the existing result if the output collection already exists. If an existing document has the same key as the new result, overwrite that existing document.
>
> reduce - Merge the new result with the existing result if the output collection already exists. If an existing document has the same key as the new result, apply the reduce function to both the new and the existing documents and overwrite the existing document with the result.

reference:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#output-to-a-collection-with-an-action